# How to use Asp.Net Ajax UpdatePanel inside an usercontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have a very simple user control like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebUserControl1.ascx.cs" Inherits="tebimir.sections.WebUserControl1" %>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</ContentTemplate>

<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
</Triggers>

</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And I have a page ajax.aspx like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ajax.aspx.cs" Inherits="tebimir.ajax" %>

<%@ Register Src="~/sections/WebUserControl1.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="WebUserControl1" %>


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <uc1:WebUserControl1 runat="server" ID="WebUserControl1" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is Button1 click code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
```

I want to update my label text to current date time without refreshing page but every time i click on button page is refreshed. why?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any other triggers in your user control because I don't see a closing tag for `</asp:UpdatePanel>`.I've created a brand new ASP.NET web forms web application and created the following user control and it works just fine(without refresh):

**User control:**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebUserControl1.ascx.cs" Inherits="StackOverflowClean.WebUserControl1" %>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>

    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Page that calls the user control:**

```
<%@ Register Src="~/WebUserControl1.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="WebUserControl1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <uc1:WebUserControl1 runat="server" id="WebUserControl1" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I dont have any other control. it is still refreshing the page. it is nonsense really

Comment: it is getting me angry. i hate it. maybe it is about visual studio 2013?

Comment: I'm also using 2013 but it's working.Try create a new project and do it over.Make sure you don't have a script manager in the master page as well for example,if you are using master pages